# Modifies the key but doesn't actually modify the value?

Tags: arrays, lua, indexing, lua-table

```
players={}
players["foo"] =
        {
            wins = 0, deaths = 0, draws = 0, rounds = 0, bet = "None", rank = 0
        }
modify = function (stat, set, target)
    local player = players[target]
    local dictionary = 
            {
            ["wins"] = player.wins, ["deaths"] = player.deaths, 
            ["draws"] = player.draws, ["rounds"] = player.rounds, 
            ["bet"] = player.bet, ["rank"] = player.rank,
            }
    if dictionary[stat] then
        dictionary[stat] = set
        print(dictionary[stat])
        print(player.wins)
    end
end

modify("wins", 1, "foo")
```

The code mentioned above doesn't really function as it's supposed to. It modifies the key "wins" but the value it's self (player[target].wins) isn't modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric values aren't references. You get copies when you copy them not references back to their original locations.

So when you assign `["wins"] = player.wins` you aren't getting a reference to the `wins` field in the player table. You are copying the value into the `dictionary` table.

If you want to modify the player table you need to modify the player table.

Also the indirection in that function is entirely unnecessary. You can reference `player[stat]` just the same as you can reference `dictionary[stat]`.

`tbl.stat` is [syntactic sugar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2)[1] for `tbl["stat"]`.

Additionally, as seen in [`§2.5.7`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7) of the lua manual:

```
tbl = {
    stat = 0,
}
```

is the same as

```
tbl = {
    ["stat"] = 0,
}
```

when the name is a string, does not start with a number, and is not a reserved token.

[1] See the `The type table` paragraph.

Comment: oh i thought it wouldnt work as the stat would be a string thanks!

Comment: `tbl.stat` is syntactic sugar for `tbl["stat"]`. See my edit.